# Swiftui how to show an image if user selected a button 2 views before

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I want to show a flag in the main view if the user selected that country 2 views before getting to the main view.

The code for the page where the user selects the country is:

```
struct ChooseLanguageWithButtonView: View {
    
    @State var isSelected1 = false
    @State var isSelected2 = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            VStack {
                ScrollView (showsIndicators: false) {
                    VStack(spacing: 20){
                        VStack(alignment: .leading){
                                Text("Choose the language you want to learn!")
                                       .font(.custom("Poppins-Bold", size: 25))
                               Text("Select one language")
                                       .opacity(0.5)
                                       .font(.custom("Poppins-Light", size: 15))
                                       .frame(alignment: .bottomTrailing)
                                       .padding(5)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        .padding(.top, -25)
                        
                        HStack (spacing: 30){
                            ButtonLanguage(
                                isSelected: $isSelected1,
                                color: .orangeGradient1,
                                textTitle: "English",
                                textSubtitle: "American",
                                imageLang: "englishAmerican",
                                imageFlag: "1"
                            )
                                .onTapGesture(perform: {
                                    
                                    isSelected1.toggle()
                                    
                                    if isSelected1 {
                                        isSelected2 = false
                                        
                                    }
                                })
                            
                            ButtonLanguage(
                                isSelected: $isSelected2,
                                color: .orangeGradient1,
                                textTitle: "English",
                                textSubtitle: "British",
                                imageLang: "telephone",
                                imageFlag: "0"
                            )
                                .onTapGesture(perform: {
                                    
                                    isSelected2.toggle()
                                    
                                    if isSelected2 {
                                        isSelected1 = false
                                        
                                    }
                                })
                        }

 
       NavigationLink(destination: {
                    if isSelected1 {
                       EnglishAmericanLevelView()
                    } else if isSelected2 {
                       EnglishBritishView() 
                    } 
                        
                    
                }, label: {
                    Text("Let's Go")
                        .bold()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                        .cornerRadius(40)
                    
                })
```

On the main view if the user chose english american I want to show the american flag.
Someone can help me with that please?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using MVVM pattern, then you can create a published Bool variable in the ViewModel and pass it in the environment.
Something passed in the environment can be accessed from all descendents of the view.

```
class MainViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showAmericanFlag: Bool = false
}
```

Pass the ViewModel it to either the MainView or ChildView as an environment object.

```
// Wherever you are using MainView
MainView()
    .environmentObject(MainViewModel())

// or create MainViewModel inside MainView and pass it to ChildView
struct MainView: View {
    private var mainViewModel = MainViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        // stuff
        ChildView()
            .environmentObject(mainViewModel())
        // stuff
    }
}
```

You can get a reference to the MainViewModel inside the ChildView from the
environment and use the `showAmericanFlag` variable.

```
struct ChildView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var mainViewModel: MainViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        // stuff
        if mainViewModel.showAmericanFlag {
            Image("americanFlag")
        }
        // stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @AxonDragonScale it makes totally sense.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a global class might be good to use here, so you can set variables like this that later you can reference in your views.

```
final class GlobalClass: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var showFlag: Bool = false
}
```

In your main project app file you can initialize the class with the `.environmentObject` method

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(GlobalClass())
        }
    }
}
```

You can then reference the global class in any view as follows

```
@EnvironmentObject private var globalObj: GlobalClass
```

Then you can set the variable to be whatever you'd like and then use it in an if statement to show your image. For example . . .

```
if (globalObj.showFlag){
    Image("flag").onTapGesture{
        globalObj.showFlag = false
    }
}
```

Otherwise you will have to pass the show flag object from view to view